# Push my values to top of auto completion list in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

I'm using a custom completer that pulls values from a server using `jQuery.getJSON`.

My custom completions are showing up along with `local` and `snippets` and I'd like mine to always be at the top. I was thinking `score` would do that but not working like this. I'm giving score a value of 1000.

```
var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true
});
var myCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        if (prefix.length === 0) {
            callback(null, []);
            return;
        }
        $.getJSON("/server/completions", function(json) {
            callback(null, json.map(function(c) {
                return {value: c.value, caption: c.caption, meta: c.meta, score:c.score};
            }));
        })
    }
};
langTools.addCompleter(myCompleter);
```

Any ideas? Thanks, /w

Comment: I have a functioning project at https://github.com/wsams/ace-editor-demo

Answer (score 1):

make sure completions you provide have higher score than default ones. default completers all give score 0, so something like  `{..., score:100 + (c.score || 0)};` should work

Comment: In my example would that be the location to return a score - in the `callback()`? I'm returning 1000.

Comment: score is defined separately for each completion. In your code you can replace `score:c.score}` (in `json.map`) with `score:100 + (c.score || 0)}`. `score:1000}` will work too

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional processing on the score done in autocomplete.js (https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/4a55188fdb0eee9e2d3854f175e67408a1e47655/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L488), based on a distance. What some ace plugins do (see for example https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/4a55188fdb0eee9e2d3854f175e67408a1e47655/lib/ace/mode/html_completions.js#L300) is set the score to `Number.MAX_VALUE`, and it works for me too: my completions appear on top of the list.